# Redemption Cannot add Item to Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook-redemption

I'm writing a program in C# using Redemption to iterate through the *RDOMail* objects in a *RDOPstStore* and copy the ones marked as relevant to a new *RDOPstStore*. I can modify the folders in the *RDOPstStore.IPMRootFolder*, and do so to only leave one folder (Results). However when I go to add *RDOMail* items to this folder (saved in a list previously) the items do not appear in the folders *Items* member. Is there something I am missing in order to ensure the "added" RDOMail object is saved in the *RDOPstStore* object? Here is the code

```
//create an output session 
RDOSession outputSession = new RDOSession(@"Redemption.RDOSession");

//logon/create output store
outputStore = outputSession.LogonPstStore(outputDir + '\\' + filename);

//clear the output store of any folders, we will leave only one: Results
foreach (RDOFolder folder in outputStore.IPMRootFolder.Folders)
{
       folder.Delete(); //successful
}
RDOFolder resultsFolder = outputStore.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Add("Results");

foreach(RDOMail mail in relevantItems) //relevantItems gathered previously
{
        resultsFolder.Items.Add(mail); //unsuccessful
        resultsFolder.Save();
}

/******************EDIT 5/26****************/
outputStore.Save();
outputSession.Logoff();
/******************END EDIT*****************/
```

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I was able to discover the issue. @Dmitry Streblechenko was right that I did not need to add a new PST Store after logging onto the Pst Store (which creates a new file if necessary).

BUT the true issue was in copying files to the newly created PST Store. The problem was using the `RDOFolder.Items.Add(RDOMail)` function. As intuitive as this `Add()` function may be the correct (or at the very least effective) approach is to use the `RDOMail.CopyTo(RDOMail/RDOFolder)` function. As so...

```
mail.CopyTo(resultsFolder);
```

This successfully placed the RDOMail object into the RDOFolder object, whereas the Add() function wouldn't. As a side note I read up another post @Dmitry helped on and he mentions that the `Add()` function is used to create new items, so it may not be completely useless. Although it seems that one could create a new RDOMail object, modify it, then use it's `CopyTo()` function...

Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

Wait a second, you were not saving the message that you added - you called save on the *folder* instead of the *item* returned by Items.Add:

```
RDOMail item = resultsFolder.Items.Add(mail);
item.Save();
```

Comment: Not so intuitive by redemption, but good catch. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: No problem at all! This is how both Redemption and the Outlook Object Model work...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, LogonPstStore returns an instance of the RDOPstStore object - there is no reason to retrieve it from the Stores collection or add it a second time.

```
outputStore  = outputSession.LogonPstStore(outputDir + '\\' + filename);
```

Secondly, PST provider commits the changes to the PST file at a later point or when the session is closed. Does your app terminate gracefully? Do you call RDOSession.Logoff?

Comment: Thanks for proposing an answer! The app is a desktop app geared to perform multiple runs of the pst manipulation and so terminating the app isn't an option. Is this a problem? I do log the session off (see edits) which I presumed was the way to commit changes, but this isn't working. How can I synchronously commit the changes in code?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to terminate the app (which is a bad idea), but rather making sure that your app is terminated gracefully. Is there a tmp file left after your app terminates in the same folder where the PST file  resides?